# Scrolling Layout with CSS display tables

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm trying to make a two column layout using display tables, however I can't figure out how to make this a fixed height (height of browser) and have the "cells" scroll to show content when it overflows.

I thought this would be a simple thing to do but it is surprisingly difficult.

As you can see I've tried even adding a special `.scroll` `<div>` which does pretty much nothing.

### HTML

```
<div class="dashboard">
    <div class="side panel">
        <div class="scroll">
            <div style="height: 400px">
            asdfasdf
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main panel">
        <div style="height: 400px">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
html, body, .dashboard {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; height: 100%;
    left: 0; right: 0;  width: 100%;
}
.dashboard {
    display: table;
}
.panel {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.panel .scroll {
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
}
.side.panel {
    width: 200px;
}
```

#### SCSS: http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKyle/j7U5E/

#### CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKyle/fScW3/

Comment: [Fix display: table height overflow-y (scroll)](http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=3854)

Answer (score 1):

Use `overflow-y: scroll;` instead of using `overflow: auto;`, because `overflow: auto;` increases the height of your div but won't make it scroll the content inside...

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fScW3/5/)

Comment: Better, but it still seems to have problems. I had originally added the 400px tall div so that it would show scrolls. It causes problems that I don't quite understand but switching to your version: http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKyle/fScW3/

Comment: check this out http://jsfiddle.net/fScW3/8/ , you need to giv a height to your `div`

Comment: In that case when the viewport is larger it keeps it at 400px;

Comment: yes it will, if you specify a height it will keep it whatever viewport is, you need dynamic height widths?

Comment: Take this for example: http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKyle/3FaVN/
On larger screens this works fine. I just need the table-cells to match the height and then scroll everything that overflows it

Comment: scroll wont apply unless and until you give height to the container div

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17520/discussion-between-james-kyle-and-mr-alien)